# Rails create new records based on checked records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table showing time entries (`events`) related to a `workorder`.
The user can enter a check on any of the table rows.
For each checked row, I want to create a new record in the `invtime` table.

`invtime` `belongs_to :event`

`event` `has_many :invtimes`

This is the table:

```
  <table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Employee</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Hours</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% Event.where("workorder_id = ?", Invoice.find(@invoice).workorder_id).where("billed = ?", false).each do |event| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag(:add_record) %></td>
      <td><%= event.title %></td>
      <td><%= event.employee.employee_full_name %></td>
      <td><%= event.starts_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></td>
      <td><%= event.hours %></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm not sure how to process the returned page with the checkboxes checked.
Should I use Javascript (coffeescript)? Or can I do it with Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<tbody>
  <%= form_tag(your_path_helper) do %>
    <% Event.where("workorder_id = ?", Invoice.find(@invoice).workorder_id).where("billed = ?", false).each do |event| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag 'event_ids_to_save[]', value: event.id, checked: Invtime.exists?(event_id: event.id) %></td>
        <td><%= event.title %></td>
        <td><%= event.employee.employee_full_name %></td>
        <td><%= event.starts_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></td>
        <td><%= event.hours %></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    <tr><td colspan='6'><%= submit_tag %></td></tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

The corresponding action of the controller responding to the form_tag submit:

```
def action_of_the_form_tag
  params[:event_ids_to_save].each do |event_id|
    event = Event.where(id: event_id)
    # do your logic here
  end
end
```

Comment: One followup - where you have `# do your logic here ` can I execute the `new` logic in the same controller?

Comment: yes of course, but you might want to keep the logic about the Invtime in the Invtime model

Comment: Sorry #MrYoshiji I have one more question:  Shouldn't the `params[event_ids_to_save].each` be par of a `respond_to`?

Comment: Yes but you could have a method on Invtime model call `def self.generate_from_event_ids(event_ids = [])` which would only create the Invtime following the given event_ids, and return the objects created. Then these objects can be send back via a respond_to